# Should I use a Rails integer or string for this number?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my Rails 3 app, I am creating a `Book` model which contains an `ISBN` column. This `ISBN` value will be a number 13 characters long. Which type should I use to create the `ISBN` column? Should I use an `:integer` or a `:string`? What is the maximum size of an integer in Rails?

```
rails g scaffold Book title:string isbn:integer
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The maximum size of the integer depends on the database being used.  For MySQL it's 2147483648 (2^31 since it's an unsigned integer.)  I would recommend you store the ISBN as a string (likely a CHAR(13) if possible.)

Comment: not convinced by that reasoning. one can use a 64 bit integer too (10^19). books are not going to grow so fast as ISBN itself has a 10^13 search space.

Comment: True.  If I was answering this today I would recommend a BIGINT (rails `:integer, limit: 8` to force a `BIGINT`.)

Answer (score 2):

ISBN numbers also contain characters i.e hyphen(-) which obviously you cannot store in integer form. So I would recommend you to use string.

Answer (score 0):

ISBN things like this`ISBN 978-7-111-27687-6`,so obviously string is a good choice

Answer (score 0):

I think a good rule of thumb is using numerical fields when you need to do math operations on the fields (or when there is a chance you would do it at some point). If not, it is a very good candidate of being an string.

Comment: I am not sure if that should be a thumb rule. if the search space is going to be small enough and not going to exceed the max number limits in future, integer makes a very good datatype as its fast on comparison.